# Optimally sized bloom filter for two different sets

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filters

Given a set with n inserted elements and a desired false positive probability p, we can find the minimum number of bits in the bloom filter m by computing <sup>-n*ln(p)</sup>/<sub>(ln2)<sup>2</sup></sub>

Suppose we have two sets of different sizes and we want to compute their intersection using the bitwise-AND operator on their bloom filters - this means that we have to construct a bloom filter for each set that is of equal size. What is the smallest such bloom filter we could construct (we can assume that both bloom filters need to have a false positive rate below some threshold)?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimally-sized"?  What makes you think that the formula you provide gives the "required" number of bits in the Bloom filter?  (I don't know what "required" would even mean here.)  Have you read the Wikipedia article on Bloom filters?

Comment: Optimally-sized refers to the smallest bloom filter that yields the desired false probability rate. To achieve a certain false probability rate, a bloom filter requires a certain number of bits. The language I used and the formula referenced are nearly identical to that of the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Optimal_number_of_hash_functions)

Comment: Are tests made for each set with equal frequency or is the check frequency proportional to the set size (or is there some other frequency distribution)? (p_all = f1*p1 + f2*p2)

Comment: Can you edit the question to incorporate this information into the question?  We want questions to stand on their own (so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking), and we want questions to be read well for someone on their own.  Note that Wikipedia does *not* say that number of bits is "required"; it says that is the number of bits that minimizes the false positive probability -- you left out some context.

Comment: Second, why do you want them to have the same size?  That formula shows that if you use the same value of $p$ for both and a different value of $n$, you get a different number of bits.  Is there something more to say?

Comment: In the equation I refer to, we are using a fixed false positive rate to find the minimum required number of bits in the bloom filter. I have edited the question to (hopefully) make it more clear. You are correct about the bloom filters being of different sizes given the same p and different n's - I have revised the question to say that we're looking for two bloom filters of equal size that have a false positive rate below some p.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think the solution may be replacing the n from the equation referenced in the question to the cardinality of the union of the two sets, which would be unfortunate given that is essentially what I need the bloom filters for in the first place.